# I need 2 posts, but, only shows 1 - WP_Query

Tags: wordpress

I'm using this wp_query. I want to show 2 posts on my sidebar, but, it is showing only one - the loop have any wrong config? thank you!

[image: The content is on a row of bootstrap and the sidebar have 3 cols]

```
                       <?php                            
                        $destaque = new WP_Query('post_type=post&posts_per_page=1&cat=2,3,4,5');
                        if($destaque->have_posts()):
                            while($destaque->have_posts()):
                                $destaque->the_post();
                        ?>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <?php get_template_part('content','homepost'); ?>
                            </div>

                        <?php
                            endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
                        endif;
                         ?>

                        <?php  
                        $args = array(
                            'post_type'         =>  'post',
                            'posts_per_page'    =>  2,
                            'category__not_in'  =>  array(1),
                            'category__in'      =>  array(2,3,4,5),
                            'offset'            =>  1
                        );

                        $secundarias = new WP_Query($args);

                        if($secundarias->have_posts()):
                            while($secundarias->have_posts()):
                                $secundarias->the_post();
                        ?>

                        <?php
                            endwhile;
                             wp_reset_postdata();
                        endif;

                         ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don t know why you have two queries, but it would simply be

```
$new_query = new WP_Query();
$new_query->query('post_type=post&showposts=2');
```

or in your example

```
('posts_per_page=2');
```

On your first query you set that to "1".
Use a single query with that before your loop and it should work.

Also check your categories - sometimes it is just

Comment: Thank you! Worked out right by deleting the query and editing